# select2 dynamic data values without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, x-editable

I have a backbone collection from which i am generating option values dynamically.

Of course backbone models attributes can be changed even without making any ajax request. Only client side changes.

I am using x-editable http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#select2

with help of which i am rendering option values for select2.

from docs i found i can provide a `source` option which can be a function

So i provided `source` as the function with generates the option values for select2 embedded with x-editable.

But nothing happens when the collection data/ models data changes.

How to solve this problem??

here is what i am currently doing (which does not work after changing collection data)

```
$('#state').editable({
        source: function(){
           return _.pluck(StateCollection, 'KEY');
         }
    });
```

the option value remain same even if the 'KEY' of any model in StateCollection changes.
Why is this so? And how to solve this problem?

EDIT : taking example of this : http://jsfiddle.net/wQysh/339/

How do i keep track of all addition, deletion and updation in the sources array and sync instantly with the select2 (current value and values available should be synced) ?

Comment: You should probably re-apply the widget when the data changes. listen to "add" and "change" events, and call `editable` again.

Comment: this is not desired, at least by me. Also re-setting the source for editable is also not desirable.

Comment: what if there is no use of backbone.. only some array is being used. Checkout the updated question